# Label data is not updating while table row data updated

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a TableViewer where rows data is updating at runtime , When I select a row then data will print on a label but if selected row data will update then how can i print updated data on label or how can i bind selected row data with label so if table row value will change then label value should also get change in SWT.

Comment: You talk about binding - are you using JFace data binding?

Comment: I am new in JFace so I don't know, how to bind data inJFace

Comment: JFace data binding is too complex for a SO answer, read a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) for that.

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: The plain TableViewer doesn't generate any events with refresh or setInput is used so you would have to craft something yourself. Perhaps make the content provider fire an event when the contents are updated.

Comment: @Nimish You may want to add label as a listener to the events of changes to table model. In the listener see if there is a row selected and if it is your ( i.e. desired ) row, get the data and update display of your label. Also it will help you get an answer if you show some code.